# How do I represent this short as a binary string with spaces and 0's in C?

Tags: c, string

I have the following Code and I'm trying to return a string with the Binary in "0000 0000 0000" format. This works except there is an extra 0 at the end of the string and I have not clue how to fix it. So instead of being "0000 0000 1100" to represent 12 it turns into "0000 0001 1000"

```
    void convert_to_binary (short acc, char *bin){
   //char bin[16] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
   /* Copies decimal value to temp variable */  
    short decimal, tempDecimal;  
    int index = 0;  
    tempDecimal = acc;  
    int length = strlen(bin);
    for (index=0; index <19;index++){
        
        if ( index % 4 == 0){
            bin[index] == ' ';
        } else if (tempDecimal!=0){
            bin[index] = (tempDecimal % 2) + '0';  

            tempDecimal /= 2;  
            //index++;  
        } else {
            bin[index] == '0';
        }
    }
    bin[index] = '\0';  

    strrev(bin);  
} // convert acc to binary str for output
```

Comment: Use a debugger?

Comment: It will be easier for you to work out the problem if you remove the unused variables (e.g. length and decimal) and format your code a bit. Also `bin[index] == '0';` looks like a typo.

Comment: regarding; `int length = strlen(bin);`   This seems to be trying to get the number of characters is an array that has not been set to any specific value.  The result is undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- `bin[index] == '0';` does not output a `0` because you use the comparison operator `==` instead of an assignment operator `=`
- the same applies for this line `bin[index] == ' ';`
- use and pay attention to compiler warnings, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c` the compiler warns about the points mentioned above and about unused variables
- you want to have every 5th character as space and not every 4th, therefore use `index % 5` instead of `index % 4`
- Your loop condition is `index <19`, it should actually be `index < 15`, if you want to output three groups of 4 characters each, you probably don't want such a constant hard-coded in such a routine
- minor: some library implementations conveniently include `strrev`, but if the goal is to write portable C, you may not use it

If you apply the above points, the output is '0000 0000 1100', which you would like to get.

**Alternative**

You could alternatively work from left to right. So you don't need to reverse the string. You could also test if a bit is set by a bit shifting operation combined with a bit test like this:

```
bool n = (acc >> (unsigned)index) & 1u;
```

With bit operations it's recommended to work with unsigned values. The number of bits to convert could be a parameter to your function, so the signature could look like this:

```
void convert_to_binary(unsigned acc, int bits, char *bin)
```

The loop is based on the number of bits and not the number of characters to be written, so that after every 4th output of an bit an additional space character is output, so that `% 4` can be used here.

This would look like this then:

```
void convert_to_binary(unsigned acc, int bits, char *bin) {
    char *ptr = bin;
    for(int index = bits - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        bool n = (acc >> (unsigned)index) & 1u;
        *ptr++ = n ? '1' : '0';
        if(index % 4 == 0)
            *ptr++ = ' ';
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
}
```

**Test**

This few test cases:

```
int main(void) {
    char buf[40] = {0};
    convert_to_binary(0xFFFFFFFF, 32, buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    convert_to_binary(0x7FFFFFFF, 32, buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    convert_to_binary(1, 32, buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    convert_to_binary(0, 32, buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    convert_to_binary(12, 32, buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    convert_to_binary(12, 12, buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

would give the following output:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 
0000 0000 1100
```